# MySQL - Migrating some ID numbers over from randomly generated to autoincremental

Tags: mysql, database, schema, database-schema

I am in the process of rewriting a company's entire system. The original developer was a bit silly and generated ID numbers for each customer report *randomly* in his database. Each ID number is up to 7 digits long - but could be anything.

I am migrating over all his old data to our new, far more logically structured database. I obviously want to use a MySQL auto-increment for our ID field. **However, it's vital that we keep the old ID numbers as customers still phone up each day with those to reference against.**

Ideally, the perfect scenario would be we go live December 1st - everything up to December 1st is all randomly IDed, and from December 1st onwards they automatically increment starting at the highest random ID in the old database.

Is such a thing possible with MySQL without any issues? I am currently using two columns - one, our logical autoincrementing ID, and a second column called `old_id` which was being used during migration. But we need the call centre staff to only be using one ID or mass confusion will ensue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start numbering from the highest random value, just changing the field to autoincrement should be enough, the normal behaviour is that mysql won't change ids already set, and starts numbering from the highest value+1.

If you want to start from a specific value (say 10,000,000) you can set

```
ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=10000000
```

Of course, be sure to create backups and test, but it should not pose any problems at all. (Note that the old records will be stored in order of the id-field, which is random, and won't reflect the creation order.)

Answer (score 0):

As you need to keep the old IDs, I'm going to assume that you're going to create a new column for autoincrement ID that will become your primary key but keep the existing ID column and rename it (to old_id, maybe?).  I'm also going to assume you record when a customer signed up.

If you make your old ID column nullable (allow NULL as a valid value) then you can simply check whether or not the old ID column is NULL.  If it's not NULL then treat that as the ID, otherwise use the autoincrement column.

Finding a customer:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE (id = /*Put your ID here*/ AND reg_date >= /*Put the date the new regime starts here*/)
OR (id_old = /*put your ID here*/ AND reg_date < /*Put the date the new regime starts here*/)
```

This will occasionally return 2 rows so you'll have to use some other criteria to uniquely identify the customer in question.

As for associating an old customer with other tables in the database, you can always use the new ID internally throughout the entire DB once its generated.  You will have to update tables that are using the old ID as the foreign key, obviously.

```
UPDATE target_table 
JOIN customers on target_table.cust_id = customers.id_old
SET target_table.cust_id = customers.id;
```

(Note: The above is just a quick and dirty query that hasn't been tested!  I'd suggest testing on a copy of the database before you try it for real!)